# Use jq to combine two arrays of objects on a certain key

Tags: jq

I am trying to use `jq` to solve this problem.

Suppose I have the following object

```
{
  "listA": [
    {
      "id": "12345",
      "code": "001"
    }
  ]
  "listB": [
    {
      "id": "12345",
      "prop": "AABBCC"
    }
  ]
}
```

In reality my two lists are longer, but the `id` isn't repeated within each list.

How may I combine the two lists into a single list where each item is an object with the non-`id` properties for the given `id` are collected into a single object?

For example, from the object above, I'd like the following:

```
{
  "listC" : [
    {
      "id": "12345",
      "code": "001",
      "prop": "AABBCC"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way would be to concatenate the arrays, group the elements by id and map each group into a single object using `add`;

```
jq '.listA+.listB | group_by(.id) | map(add)' test.json
```

If there may be more than two arrays you need to merge in the file, you could instead use `flatten` to concatenate all of them.

Test case below

```
# cat test.json

{
  "listA": [
    { "id": "12345", "code": "001" },
    { "id": "12346", "code": "002" }
  ],
  "listB": [
    { "id": "12345", "prop": "AABBCC" }
  ]
}

# jq 'flatten | group_by(.id) | map(add)' test.json
# or
# jq '.listA+.listB | group_by(.id) | map(add)' test.json

[
  {
    "id": "12345",
    "code": "001",
    "prop": "AABBCC"
  },
  {
    "id": "12346",
    "code": "002"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `group_by` entails a sort, which is unnecessary, so if efficiency is a concern, then an alternative approach such as the following should be considered:

```
INDEX(.listA[]; .id) as $one
| INDEX(.listB[]; .id) as $two
| reduce ($one|keys_unsorted[]) as $k ($two; .[$k] += $one[$k])
| {listC: [.[]] }
```