# how can I merge the object to the array from files by jq 1.5 on linux

Tags: jq

I have two JSON files:

###### item.json

```json
{
    "id": "123456",
    "name": "David"
}
```

###### list.json

```json
[
    {
        "id": "123456",
        "age": "12"
    },
    {
        "id": "654321",
        "age": "13"
    }
]
```

---

I want to loop the `list.json` and read the `item.json` use the `id` to mapping the current item in the loop if the `id` is matched, if matched , merge it into the list item.

I tried this:

```
 jq --arg volid "$(jq -r '.["id"]' item.json)" '.[] | select(.["id"] == $volid) |= . += input' list.json
```

But something went wrong:

> ```
> jq: error: syntax error, unexpected += (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
> .[] | select(.["id"] == $volid) |= . += input                                            
> jq: 1 compile error
> ```

---

I hope the result is this

```json
[
    {
        "id": "123456",
        "name": "David", // merged
        "age": "12"
    },
    {
        "id": "654321",
        "age": "13"
    }
]
```

---

I have tried a long time but still was not able to resolve it, please help me, thank a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use jq to combine two arrays of objects on a certain key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54956517/use-jq-to-combine-two-arrays-of-objects-on-a-certain-key)

Comment: This won't work @Paolo since OP doesn't want the single object to be kept if the ID does not match anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dealing with a single object, you can use [`--slurpfile`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) to load that object into your jq filter which then you can

1. [`map()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)) over `list.json`
2. Use an [`if/else`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#if-then-else) to check if `.id` matches `$item[0].id`

   1. If so, merge them together: [`(. * $item\[0\])`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Multiplication,division,modulo:*,/,and%25)
   2. Otherwise, just keep current item (`.`)

```
jq --slurpfile item item.json \
    'map(if .id == $item[0].id then (. * $item[0]) else . end)' \
list.json
```

---

Another solution, based on your attempt using [`select()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)):

```
jq -s '.[0] as $n | .[1] | map(select(.id == $n.id) *= $n)' item.json list.json
```

1. Uses `--slurp` to get a single array containing both files
2. Remember the object we're merging: `.[0] as $n`
3. [`map()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)) over the the `list.json` (`.[1]`) array, [`select()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) matching object, and merge (`*=`) in the saved object: `$n`

---

Both options outputs:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "123456",
    "age": "12",
    "name": "David"
  },
  {
    "id": "654321",
    "age": "13"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps me solve this problem , I got the data I want.